# LiveData keeps on outputting changes to last given observable

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I am using room persistence lib and LiveData and Rx Android, I'm observing a change in id, this is the id of the song currently being played when a new song is played the id will change.

My issue when a new song is played the onNext function is still being called on the old song creating unwanted behaviour for my UI, this I suspect is because there are changes occurring to the old song and it is still subscribed.

Is there an Rx Operator to unsubscribe from the old Live Data and subscribe to the new Live Data stream, therefore only observing one song Object at a time...

```
   mDisposable.add(Observable.just(id)
                .flatMap(str -> Observable.just(Objects.requireNonNull(mViewModel.getLiveDataSong(str))))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(song ->
                        song.observe(this, mSong ->
                                mDisposable.add(Observable.just(mSong)
                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                        .subscribe(liveSong -> Log.d(TAG, "Live Song " + liveSong.toString()),
                                                error -> Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getLocalizedMessage()),
                                                () -> Log.d(TAG, "Complete " + mSong.toString()))))));
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having similar issues this may be of some use, Rather than unsubscribing from the old Live Data the Live Data must be changed upstream and the changes will propagate down, this is done using Transforms as per the Android developers best practices https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rO4r-JOQtA&t=914s

```
mViewModel.setMutableLiveItem(id);

mViewModel.getMutableLiveItem()).observe(this, song -> mDisposable.add(Observable.just(song)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(mSong -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "filtered " + mSong.toString());
                }
            })));
}
```

Then in The View Model

```
    private val mItemId = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setMutableLiveItem(mId: String) {
        this.mItemId.value = mId
    }

    fun getMutableLiveItem(): LiveData<Song>? {
        return switchMap(mItemId) { id -> getLiveDataSong(id) }
    }

    fun getLiveDataSong(mId: String): LiveData<Song> {
        return repository.getLiveDataSong(mId)
    }
```